# The options do not change on the cell phone, only on the computer

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a function in javascript, where it changes the number of options in the select according to the value that I selected in the previous select. This works normally on the computer, however when I use it on my phone and other people's, this function does not work

these are the selects:

```
<select class='opcoes' id="pecasDoJogo-1Auto" onchange="getValue('pecasDoJogo-1Auto')" onclick="changeQuantityOfOptions('pecasDoJogo-1Auto','pecasDoJogo-1TeleOp')">
                        <option value="0" >0</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="7">7</option>
                        <option value="8">8</option>
                        <option value="9">9</option>
                    </select> 

<select class='opcoes' id="pecasDoJogo-1TeleOp" onchange="getValue('pecasDoJogo-1TeleOp')" onclick="changeQuantityOfOptions('pecasDoJogo-1TeleOp','pecasDoJogo-1Auto')">
                        <option value="0">0</option>
                        <option value="1" >1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="7">7</option>
                        <option value="8">8</option>
                        <option value="9">9</option>
                    </select>
```

These are the functions I'm using:

````
function getValue(nameId){
    return parseInt(document.getElementById(nameId).value)
}

function changeQuantityOfOptions(yourId,ReferenceId){
        const quantidade = 9 - parseInt(document.getElementById(yourId).value)
        const select = document.getElementById(ReferenceId)
        select.innerHTML = ""
        for(var i = 0; i <= quantidade; i++){
            select.innerHTML += `<option value="${i}">${i}</option>`
        }
}```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call your function only `onchange`, not `onclick`.

```js
function getValue(nameId){
    return parseInt(document.getElementById(nameId).value)
}

function changeQuantityOfOptions(yourId,ReferenceId){
        const quantidade = 9 - parseInt(document.getElementById(yourId).value)
        const select = document.getElementById(ReferenceId)
        select.innerHTML = ""
        for(var i = 0; i <= quantidade; i++){
            select.innerHTML += `<option value="${i}">${i}</option>`
        }
}
```

```html
<select class='opcoes' id="pecasDoJogo-1Auto" onchange="changeQuantityOfOptions('pecasDoJogo-1Auto','pecasDoJogo-1TeleOp')">
                        <option value="0" >0</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="7">7</option>
                        <option value="8">8</option>
                        <option value="9">9</option>
                    </select> 

<select class='opcoes' id="pecasDoJogo-1TeleOp" onchange="changeQuantityOfOptions('pecasDoJogo-1TeleOp','pecasDoJogo-1Auto')">
                        <option value="0">0</option>
                        <option value="1" >1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="7">7</option>
                        <option value="8">8</option>
                        <option value="9">9</option>
                    </select>
```

Comment: but there is already a function in onchange that I use, what do I do with it?

Comment: Get rid of that one. It doesn't do anything.

Comment: ok, a gonna test

Comment: thanks bro, my project is practically finished with your help! if you want to take a look, this is the link https://calculadora-de-pontos-frc-charged-up.netlify.app/

Comment: I checked your app it is nice.. but learn some color combination and UI/UX  things it help you in your next apps.. UI should be sober and neat..

Comment: Thanks bro! You can leave it, I'm constantly evolving in my code!